# program to find factorial of number using only main function

Tags: c, factorial

When i run this program it will give answer also but when selecting option n then it will again ask to enter options check it and provide good solution how it can be done

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    static int count = 0;
    static int num;
    static unsigned long long int res;
    static int temp;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter the value of Number:");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num < 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid input.");
            return 0;
        }
        temp = num;
        res = 1;
        count++;

        do {
            main();
            printf("Factorial of %d is\t:%llu\n", temp, res);
            printf("Do you want to continue y/n :");
            scanf("\n%c", &ch);

        } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
    }

    //Logic for recursive factorial function
    if (num > 0)
    {
        res = res * num;
        num = num - 1;
        main();
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "using only main function" and "good solution" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: `if (num > 0)` should be changed to `while(num > 1)` and knock out the recursion. And the recursion in the input loop. The entire program needs to be restructured.

Comment: Avoid calling `main()` recursively.   Everything you seek to do - including calculating the factorial of an entered value - can be done using loop constructs.

Comment: Ok but i want solution in which recursion is used and only in main function how to do that

Answer (score 1):

The recursive call of `main` is an absolute "no go". Never do that. Instead simply put the calculation of the factorial just after you have received the input.

I'll not call it a good solution but the code below is close to your own code and avoids the recursive call of `main`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;
    unsigned long long int res;
    int temp;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the value of Number:");
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || (num < 0))
        {
            printf("Invalid input.");
            return 0;
        }

        // Calculate
        temp = num;
        res = 1;
        while (num)
        {
          res = res * num;
          num = num - 1;
        }

        printf("Factorial of %d is\t:%llu\n", temp, res);
        printf("Do you want to continue y/n :");
        scanf("\n%c", &ch);

    } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to do with using recursion and only calling main function

Answer (score 1):

Does the recursive call of "main()" stand for reset of the program?
If so, why are you not using a infinite loop to check for input and then in the body you do factorial computing, outputs, such as prints etc., and ending the program when not needed anymore with a certain input.
I believe this should do the trick:

```
        do {
        printf("Do you want to find a factorial? Y || y to continue");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        printf("Enter the value of Number:");
        scanf("%d", &num);

//Here you do your factorial number computation and error checks

    } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

It asks again because you are calling recursively the main function in your do,while.
Not sure what you wanted to do with this recursive calling but pretty sure you should remove this line.

=> Remove "main();"

Comment: Want factorial program using recursion but only with calling main function and with do you want to continue options how to do it

Comment: @piyushkumar yes but your recursive calling of main is ok in your if. The problem is the one in the do while. You should remove it